# onPressed with Multiple Condition flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make some conditions on "Enregister" button . I want to disable button when i don't change any information ( name , adress and email ) . The button works only when i change one of theme

My code  :

```
    Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        vertical: 10),
                                                    width: size.width * 0.4,
                                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                             
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        editUserProfile();
                                                      },
                                                      child: Text('Enregistrer'),
                                                      style:
                                                          ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                        primary: Colors.transparent,
                                                        shape:
                                                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                            20),
                                                                side: BorderSide(
                                                                    color: Colors
                                                                        .white)),
                                                      ),
                                                    )),
void editUserProfile() async {
    setState(() {});

    String name = _nameController.text;
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String adress = _adressController.text;

    userApi.editUserProfile(name, email, adress).then((data) {
      print(data);
      if (data != null) {
    
      }

      setState(() {
        enableup = false;
        enableadress = false;
        enableemail = false;
      });

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(data)));

    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
    });
    setState(() {});
  }
```

[image]

How i make conditions on OnPressed to disable button works when i don't modify any text input ?

Answer (score 0):

When you edit some value pushing 'pencil' icon, changed value from false to true.

```
bool isModified = false;

...
// If Name, Email, Address is changed, change 'isModified' value and call setState to update ui.

setState(() {
   isModified = true;
}
```

After that, change 'onPressed' place like below.

```
    Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        vertical: 10),
                                                    width: size.width * 0.4,
                                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                             
                                                      onPressed: isModified ? () {
                                                        editUserProfile();
                                                      } : null,
                                                      child: Text('Enregistrer'),
                                                      style:
                                                          ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                        primary: Colors.transparent,
                                                        shape:
                                                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                            20),
                                                                side: BorderSide(
                                                                    color: Colors
                                                                        .white)),
                                                      ),
                                                    )),
```

Answer (score 0):

it is maybe helps

```
bool isProfileChanged = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _emailController.addListener(() {
      
      if (!isProfileChanged) {
        setState(() {});
      }
      isProfileChanged = true;
    });

  }


  child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: isProfileChanged ? () {
             editUserProfile();
            } : null,
        child: Text('Enregistrer'),
  );
```